# Does health and dmg scale per area?

Tags: destiny

I have noticed something pecular in the Cosmodrome of Old Russia.  Level 4s were taking as much damage as same level mobs.  Now does that mean health for Mobs are scaled to my current level, or does that mean my damage is scaled down to when I was first in the area in Story mode?
I have the Vanguard Legendary On Time to it helps to understand with all 4 legendary armor items.

Comment: Oh man, there's [this amazing post on Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/DestinyTheGame/comments/2h9t6b/this_is_how_light_levels_affect_your_gameplay_and/) that you really need to read. Not that I'm advertising Reddit (I'm not) nor am I affiliated with this individual or post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your damage is **scaled down**, and this includes **damage you do** and **damage you receive**.

Your weapon damage is decreased by the following amounts:

> Equal/Above: 0%
>   Minus 1 Level: 32%
>   Minus 2 Levels: 45%
>   Minus 3 Levels: 52%

[source](http://www.reddit.com/r/DestinyTheGame/comments/2rhgrm/weapon_damage_explained_with_science/)

As long as you are at the mob's level or above it, you will do the same amount of damage to that mob, and receive the same amount of damage from that mob. This means that for a level 4 mob, a level 4 guardian and a level 32 guardian *with the same weapon* will do the same damage and receive the same damage.

Defense is a bit trickier, and I cannot find any exact numbers. However I can confirm that there is a cap on defense for each level. That is why a level 4 dreg will do the same amount of damage to a level 4 or level 20 character, but will deal a lot more damage against a level 1.

There is no *per-area* scaling. All scaling is determined by the level difference between yourself and the mob in question. That's why Bungie has no problem placing level 20+ mobs in the Cosmodrome.

Comment: If your damage is scaled down, why would you take the same amount of damage from a level 4 mob as a level 4 guardian who has no benefits of damage scaling?

Comment: @travisj read my post, I cover *receiving damage* too. There is a defense cap of some form at every level. The entire system was designed to make it so that being overlevelled doesn't mean being overpowered. At a given level you can deal X damage and receive Y damage, and these values don't change regardless if you're the same level or 20 levels over.

Comment: From my experience you will kill bad guys at the same rate but you will die much slower at higher levels. I suspect its because the raw damage is the same for a level 4 and a level 30 but the level 30 will have much higher defence. But as a level 30 I can ignore enemies shooting at me in low level areas because I just don't care whereas when I am the same level as them I don't have that luxury (as I painfully found out recently when levelling up a new character).

Comment: @chris AFAIK there's a "defense cap" per level. So at level 4, it's very unlike that you've hit the *level 4 defense cap* but at level 10 you likely have. That seems to correlate with other information I have found online, however I cannot manage to find exact numbers.

Comment: @Thebluefish: Ah, I see what you mean. So when you were talking about "a level 4 dreg will do the same amount of damage to a level 4 or level 20 character" you were talking about a level 4 character at the level 4 defence cap? That I definitely find believable. Effectively I guess it means that there is a minimum damage that the dreg can do to you.